# Plot frequency histogram with a 4-level factor using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that I would like to put into a histogram showing the frequencies within each subset of 4 factors. I would like them to be on the same histogram and in different colors. The ..ncount.. function looks to be the best, but it is normalizing the data to a maximum of 1, while I want the SUM of all of the frequencies within a subset to be equal to 1. Here is the code I have used and the accompanying graphs:

my data file is: "assocID"
The factor is: "category"
the continuous variable that I am using for the histogram is : "QGM"

```
ggplot(assocID,aes(QGM)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1,aes(fill=category,y(..count..)),position="dodge") +
    facet_wrap(~dyad)
```

go [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt5me.jpg) to see the three output images. I am a new used to stackoverflow so they won't let me post images. I figure the graphs will explain better than the text!

Now if I use `(..count..)/sum(..count..)` that just divides by the total count, not within subsets

```
ggplot(assocID,aes(QGM)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1,aes(fill=category,y(..count..)/sum(..count..)),position="dodge") + 
    facet_wrap(~dyad)
```

finally the ncount one doesn't seem to do it either.

```
ggplot(assocID,aes(QGM)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1,aes(fill=category,y(..ncount..)),position="dodge") + 
    facet_wrap(~dyad)
```

basically I want to show a histogram of frequencies WITHIN each factor of the variable "category"

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is tough because your example isn't reproducible, but I'll take a stab that you are looking for `..density..`, which per the [documentation](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_bin.html) for `stat_bin` will yield a value that integrates to one.

Also, I'm assuming that `y(..count..)` was intended to be `y = ..count..`?